# How can I enable my MacBook Pro GPU optimization for theano?

Tags: macos, gpu, theano

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)
- OS X Yosemite 10.10.3
- Intel Iris 1536MB

[Installing Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#using-the-gpu) shows I need CUDA, but I do not have NVIDIA, that means I can never enable GPU optimization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct: an NVIDIA graphics processor is currently required to enable Theano's GPU operation. However, that does not prevent you from running Theano -- it works just fine on the CPU.

Theano's current GPU implementation is based on CUDA and thus requires an NVIDIA GPU. A new implementation based on OpenCL is in development which should enable operation on non-NVIDIA GPUs, but this implementation is incomplete and not yet practically useful.

The CPU implementation will work fine. In many ways it is easier to use than the GPU implementation and, if you use OpenMP, can still perform reasonably well by utilizing many CPU cores.

Comment: I have heard [that](https://www.kaggle.com/lukasz8000/digit-recognizer/test1/discussion) in some extreme situation GPU can run more than 60 times faster than CPU, is that true? within Theano programming.

Comment: The current claim on the Theano homepage is "up to 140 times faster on GPU compared to CPU". But this claim was substantiated in 2010 and a lot of improvements have been made to both CPU and GPU implementations since then; it's also very task specific so YMMV.

Comment: I have the MCB Retina display that came with GT 750 M. That gives me about 70X more performance than the CPU which is a 4th gen i7. I use cuDNN 3, with CUDA 7.5, I think.